# How can I query a SharePoint List for different ContentTypes?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am developing a console application to extract data from a SharePoint 2013 server using the [.NET client object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Dn423226.aspx#bk_QueryNETcsom) of the [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585):

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(SharePointUrl))
{
    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    var camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
    var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems, GetFields(fields));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    return listItems.ToList();
}
```

This is the GetFields() method I call to construct the list of fields I request:

```
private Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>[] GetFields(IEnumerable<string> fields)
{
    return fields
        .Select(field => (Expression<Func<ListItemCollection, object>>)(items => items.Include(item => item[field])))
        .ToArray();
}
```

---

There is one big list -- `"Demands"` -- that is giving me troubles for some User-type fields: **whenever I include these as a field that needs to be retrieved** via the `GetFields()` method (see above), **I get [the infamous "Value does not fall within the expected range." error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/105397/45188)**. For instance, `"DTBusinessResponsible"` can be retrieved, yet `"DTSupplyLeadResponsible"` cannot.

I have been informed that `"Demands"` contains two `ContentTypes`: `"Demand"` and `"I-Demand"`. The fields that are giving me issues are exclusive to `"I-Demand"`.

---

I cannot figure out how I can retrieve these problematic fields. I've tried retrieving the `ContentType`s for `"Demand"` and `"I-Demand"` and adding them to `list`:

```
var demandContentType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(contentTypeByName["Demand"]);
var iDemandContentType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById(contentTypeByName["I-Demand"]);

list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType(demandContentType);
list.ContentTypes.AddExistingContentType(iDemandContentType);
```

But this is no use, I get an error telling me both `ContentType`s are already present.

---

(Note that [I have already asked this over at the SharePoint SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/156640/45188), but I didn't get any useful responses there.)

---

**EDIT: Let's simplify the question.**

I need to retrieve a number of fields from a SharePoint List called `"Demands"`. To that end, I add the fields I require as [`Expression<Func<T, object>>[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj171831.aspx).

However, some of the fields I need to retrieve are exclusive to `"I-Demand"`, which is one of the `ContentTypes` of the `"Demands"` list. Whenever I add those fields, the query crashes and produces [the infamous "Value does not fall within the expected range." error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/105397/45188). I have no trouble retrieving dozens of other fields which are all part of the `"Demand"` content type.

How can I retrieve those fields that are exclusive to the `"I-Demand"` content type?

---

**EDIT: Here's what doesn't work...**

```
var fields = new List<string>
{
    "DTBusinessRequestor",
    "DTBusinessResponsible",
    "DTBusinessSponsor",
    "DTDemandAccountable",
    "DTIICTBusinessAnalyst",
    "DTSupplyAccountable",
    "DTSupplyLeadResponsible",
    "Title",
    "Author",
    "Created",
    "Editor",
    "Modified",
    "ID"
};

var viewXml = new StringBuilder();

viewXml.AppendLine("<ViewFields>");
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    viewXml.AppendFormat("<FieldRef Name=\"{0}\" />", field).AppendLine();
}
viewXml.AppendLine("</ViewFields>");

var camlQuery = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = string.Format("<View>{0}</View>", viewXml) };

List<ListItem> results;

using (var clientContext = GetClientContext())
{
    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Demands");
    var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    results = listItems.ToList();
}

var validNames = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var listItem in results)
{
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        object value;
        if (!listItem.FieldValues.TryGetValue(field, out value))
            continue;

        if (value != null)
        {
            validNames.Add(field);
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code:

- `results` contains 10 (ten) items while there are 160 entries in SharePoint;
- `validNames` contains six fields: "Title", "Author", "Created", "Editor", "Modified", "ID".

Which is a slightly better result than the one I had, since "Author" and "Editor" were problematic. The rest of the fields return null, but that could be because the ten results do not have values. However, I cannot compare to the values in SharePoint since the ten titles that are returned are ***not*** ones that are found in the Demands table...

---

I try to filter by ContentType by adding this line after `viewXml.AppendLine("</ViewFields>");`:

```
viewXml.AppendLine("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>I-Demand</Value></Eq></Where></Query>");
```

Result: `results` contains no entries.

---

I remove the filter by ContentType and change this:

```
var camlQuery = new CamlQuery { ViewXml = string.Format("<View>{0}</View>", viewXml) };
```

to this:

```
var camlQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View>{0}</View>", viewXml);
```

Same result as originally: ten items, same fields.

I then remove this line:

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View>{0}</View>", viewXml);
```

Result: 160 items, values for "DTBusinessRequestor", "DTBusinessResponsible", "DTBusinessSponsor" and "DTIICTBusinessAnalyst" ***BUT*** no results for "Author" and "Editor" -- so I'm back where I started.

---

I have not found a single solution where it returns me values for all 160 entries in the Demands list combined with values for "Author" and "Editor" and also "DTDemandAccountable", "DTSupplyAccountable" and "DTSupplyLeadResponsible" (where applicable).

Whenever I add `<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>I-Demand</Value></Eq></Where></Query>` I get zero results.

Comment: No usable answers typically means a problem with the question. You won't get a better answer in a *generalist* site than in a specialized one. In this case, the actual question is lost in the code that tries to implement some sort of dynamic query generation. I can't even see what is being queried and where.

Comment: That said, SharePoint queries *are* CAML queries. In a CAML query you can filter by the ContetnTypeId. There *are* several answers about this in SharePoint SE. You need to add a similar filter condition to your query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The specialized site seems far less popular, hence me repeating the question here. I've posted the code to show how I am working, since there are so many ways of querying SharePoint. I've added a simplified version of my question at the bottom, though I feel my original question outlined the problem well enough, by drawing focus to the bolded part.

Comment: Actually, it confused things more. This isn't about lambdas. Your query should be filtering by ContentTypeId - where does it do that? I suggest you first create a CAML query that returns what you want, then try to make a generic querying mechanism, if needed. Also note that the client model *does* allow you to use CAML - you could get one of the queries in SharePoint SE and execute it.

Comment: Finally, look for tools that help you create and execute CAML queries like [CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.be/Software), [Caml Query Helper](https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/) or [CamlDesigner](http://www.camldesigner.com/?p=594).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through much trial and error, I have managed to get this to work:

```
var fields = new List<string>
{
    "DTSupplyAccountable",
    "DTSupplyLeadResponsible",
    "Author",
    "Editor",
    "ID"
};

var viewXml = new StringBuilder();

viewXml.AppendLine("<ViewFields>");
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    viewXml.AppendFormat("<FieldRef Name=\"{0}\" />", field).AppendLine();
}
viewXml.AppendLine("</ViewFields>");

viewXml.AppendLine("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\" /><Value Type=\"Computed\">I-Demand</Value></Eq></Where></Query>");

var camlQuery = new CamlQuery {ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">{0}</View>", viewXml)};

List<ListItem> results;

using (var clientContext = GetClientContext())
{
    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Demands");
    var listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(listItems);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    results = listItems.ToList();
}
```

Here is the crucial detail (apart from the obvious `<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\" /><Value Type=\"Computed\">I-Demand</Value></Eq></Where>`):

```
ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">{0}</View>", viewXml)
```

In fact, it's `Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"` that is the important part. I encountered it when looking with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to the various requests that were sent to the server and noticing that the working calls all included this:

```xml
<Property Name="ViewXml" Type="String">&lt;View Scope="RecursiveAll"&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;Query&gt;&#xD;
    &lt;/Query&gt;&#xD;
&lt;/View&gt;</Property>
```

On a whim I decided to add `Scope="RecursiveAll"` to my code, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Construct two separate caml queries, each specifying one or the other content type.  Then, take the results, and read them into your own data objects (e.g. POCO objects -- Plain Old C# Objects).  Once they are in your Poco data objects, you can use Linq to merge the datasets, which you can then consume.

You can write generic methods to read the ListItem data into POCO objects, so this can be a reusable approach to use whenever you encounter this issue.

Comment: Please note the edit I just made which lists various solutions I've tried. I have not found any way to "specify one or the other content type" other than adding a `Where` to the Caml and this always results in zero values being returned.

Comment: What about filtering by ContentTypeId.  Not ContentType.  See e.g. https://kerseub.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/using-contenttypeid-in-caml-query/